# strtok function and multithreading

Tags: c, multithreading

I read a lot of stuff about strtok(char* s1, char* s2) and its implementation. However, I still can not understand what makes it a dangerous function to use in multi-threaded program. Can somebody please give me an example of a multi-threaded program and explain the issue there? Please not that I am looking for an example that shows me where the problem arises.

ps: strtok(char* s1, char* s2) is part of the C standard library.

Comment: "what makes it a dangerous function to use in multi-threaded program." - not being  thread safe perhaps......

Comment: @MitchWheat: Is that actually the case? It would be trivial for an implementation to make the persistent state thread-local, just like with `errno`.

Comment: @MitchWheat Actually I am not looking for a substitute. I want to know the explanation behind that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a concrete example:

Suppose first that your program is multi-threaded, and in one thread of execution, the following code runs:

```
char str1[] = "split.me.up";

// call this line A
char *word1 = strtok(str1, "."); // returns "split", sets str1[5] = '\0'

// ... 

// call this line B
char *word2 = strtok(NULL, "."); // we hope to get back "me"
```

And in another thread, the following code runs:

```
char str2[] = "multi;token;string";

// call this line C
char *token1 = strtok(str2, ";"); // returns "multi", sets str2[5] = '\0'

// ...

// call this line D
char *token2 = strtok(NULL, ";"); // we hope to get back "token"
```

The point is, we don't really know what will be in `word2` and `token2`:

If the commands are run in the order (A), (B), (C), (D), then we will get what we want.

But if, say, the commands run in the order (A), (C), (B), (D), then command (B) will search for a `.` delimeter in `"token;string"`!  This is because the `NULL` first argument to command (B) tells `strtok` to continue searching in the last non-`NULL` search string it was passed, and because command (C) has already run, `strtok` will use `str2`.

Then command (B) will return `token;string`, at the same time setting the new starting character of a search to the `NUL` terminator at the end of `str2`.  Then the command (D) will think it is searching an empty string, because it will begin its search at `str2`'s `NUL` terminator, and so will return `NULL` as well.

Even if you place commands (A) and (B) right next to each other, and commands (C) and (D) right next to each other, there is no guarantee that (B) will be executed right after (A) before either (C) or (D), etc.

If you create some sort of mutex or alternate guard to protect the use of the `strtok` function, and only call `strtok` from a thread which has obtained a lock on said mutex, then `strtok` is safe to use.  However, it is probably better just to use the thread-safe `strtok_r` as others have said.

**Edit:** There is one more issue, that nobody else has mentioned, namely that `strtok` modifies and potentially uses global (or static, whatever) variables, and does so in a probably-not-thread-safe way, so even if you don't rely on repeating calls to `strtok` to get successive "tokens" from the same string, it may not be safe to use it in a multi-threaded environment without guards, etc.

Comment: Your answer cleared the issue for me, thanks. According to "http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/invisible/src/crt/strtok.c.htm", The problem happens because of this line "s1 = lastToken;". As a result, strtok ignores the passed string by replacing it with the last string that it worked on that.

Answer (score 6):

In the first call to strtok, you supply the string and the delimiters.  In subsequent calls, the first parameter is NULL, and you just supply the delimiters.  strtok remembers the string that you passed in.

In a multithreaded environment, this is dangerous because many threads may be calling strtok with different strings. It will only remember the last one and return the wrong result.

Comment: Suppose we have two threads. Thread1 calls strtok() and the first delimiter is found in index=3. Now if thread2 calls the function, strtok() starts its work from index=4 and not from index=0 of the passed string. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Its not only multi-threaded environments.  strtok is even bad in a single-threaded enviro.  If a high-level function is using strtok to parse a large object (for example, paragraphs), and then calling a lower level function that uses strtok to parse smaller objects (for example, sentences), the lower-level calls will interfere with the higher level calls.

Comment: @Nazgol not quite: thread2 will start from 0 of the passed string but when you go back to thread1, it will use thread2's string from the last position of thread2's delimiter if the first parameter is NULL.

Comment: @cup Based on this source code, http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/invisible/src/crt/strtok.c.htm, I do not understand why thread1 uses thread2's string. Can you elaborate it more?

Comment: ' static char *lastToken = NULL; /* UNSAFE SHARED STATE! */' What more do you want?

Comment: @MartinJames So, the problem is that we start searching from the wrong index as I mentioned in my second last comment.right? for instance, Thread2 starts searching from the index that thread1 finds its delimiter while we expect that thread2 starts searching from index 0. So, in multithreaded environment, each strtok operates on its own string but from the wrong index. right?

Comment: @Nazgol: Or they run simultaneously, leading to all sorts of havoc.

Answer (score 3):

To explain in simple terms, Whenever they name it THREAD safe, they literally mean, it is not just your thread, other thread too can modify it! It is like a cake been shared with 5 friends concurrently. The results are unpredictable who consumed the cake, or who altered it!

Every call to the strtok() function, returns a refrence to a NULL terminated string and it uses a static buffer during parsing. Any subsequent call to the function will refer to that buffer only, and it gets altered.! It is independent of who called it, and thats is the reason for it is not thread safe.

Other hand strtok_r() using a additional 3rd argument called saveptr(we need to specify it)  which is probably used to hold that reference for subsequent calls. Thus is no more system specific but in developer control.

**An example**:( from a book of Steven robbins, unix system programming)

An incorrect use of strtok to determine the average number of words per line.

```
#include <string.h>
#define LINE_DELIMITERS "\n"
#define WORD_DELIMITERS " "

static int wordcount(char *s) {
   int count = 1;

   if (strtok(s, WORD_DELIMITERS) == NULL)
      return 0;
   while (strtok(NULL, WORD_DELIMITERS) != NULL)
      count++;
   return count;
}

double wordaverage(char *s) {      /* return average size of words in s */
   int linecount = 1;
   char *nextline;
   int words;

   nextline = strtok(s, LINE_DELIMITERS);
   if (nextline == NULL)
      return 0.0;
   words = wordcount(nextline);
   while ((nextline = strtok(NULL, LINE_DELIMITERS)) != NULL) {
      words += wordcount(nextline);
      linecount++;
   }
   return (double)words/linecount;
}
```

The `wordaverage` function determines the average number of words per line by using `strtok` to find the next line. The function then calls `wordcount` to count the number of words on this line. Unfortunately, `wordcount` also uses `strtok`, this time to parse the words on the line. Each of these functions by itself would be correct if the other one did not call `strtok`. The `wordaverage` function works correctly for the first line, but when `wordaverage` calls `strtok` to parse the second line, the internal state information kept by `strtok` has been reset by `wordcount`.