# Is strtok() safe to use

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

I am reading a lot negative things about `strtok()`, some say it is obsolete, some say it is not thread safe, etc.

So what is the truth, can I use `strtok()`? and is it thread safe?

**Note:** I am using Visual C++.

Comment: Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4031075/strtok-function-thread-safety

Comment: Some related questions with answers are displayed to the right (look for "Related"), for example [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20820937/509868)

Comment: In general you should avoid using the C standard library when writing C++ code - use proper C++ data types and idioms instead.

Comment: What research have you performed?

Comment: `strok` is not thread-safe, it uses a static buffer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use it, it's a part of the standard library.

It uses internal storage that is shared across all users of the function, so *no* it's not thread-safe.

It also *modifies* the string you hand to it, which is quite scary.

I would not recommend using it, in most cases.

Answer (score 5):

`strtok()` is "safe" in that it is possible to use it and not have any bugs. However, if you're programming C++ rather than C, you should use C++ string facilities to mess with strings, rather than relying on the legacy C functions. Things like `std::string` and `std::stringstream` will give you far more flexibility than `strtok`, while making logic bugs less likely.

Answer (score 1):

As said by unwind you can use it, `strtok` is safe in Visual C++ but not elsewhere. One issue which is there with `strtok` is that static buffer is used by `strtok()` function while parsing, so it's not thread safe. `strtok_s` is an alternative for it. From [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1173.pdf):

> 6.7.3.1 The strtok_s function The strtok_s function fixes two problems
>   in the strtok function:
>
> 1. A new parameter, s1max, prevents strtok_s from storing outside of the
>      string being tokenized. (The string
>      being divided into tokens is both an
>      input and output of the function since
>      strtok_s stores null characters into
>      the string.)
> 2. A new parameter, ptr, eliminates the static internal state that
>      prevents strtok from being re-entrant
>      (Subclause 1.1.12). (The ISO/IEC 9899
>      function wcstok and the ISO/IEC 9945
>      (POSIX) function strtok_r fix this
>      problem identically.)