# Why do I keep getting compiler errors with strtok in C?

Tags: c, function, strtok

My assignment is to create a progrma that asks the users for a date then prints if its valid or not. I am only allowed to use strings and no int %d.

Why does my program get so many compiler errors dealing with the strtok and calling the function?

```
 Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning C4024   'getInput': different types for formal and actual parameter 1   dating  c:\users\chris\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\dating\dating.c    26  
Warning C4047   'function': 'char *' differs in levels of indirection from 'char'   dating  c:\users\chris\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\dating\dating.c    26  
Warning C4024   'getInput': different types for formal and actual parameter 2   dating  c:\users\chris\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\dating\dating.c    26  
Warning C4024   'getInput': different types for formal and actual parameter 3   dating  c:\users\chris\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\dating\dating.c    26  
Warning C4996   'scanf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using scanf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details. dating  c:\users\chris\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\dating\dating.c    19  
Warning C4996   'strtok': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using strtok_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.   dating  c:\users\chris\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\dating\dating.c    21  
Warning C4996   'strtok': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using strtok_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.   dating  c:\users\chris\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\dating\dating.c    22  
Warning C4996   'strtok': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using strtok_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.   dating  c:\users\chris\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\dating\dating.c    24  
Warning C4098   'getInput': 'void' function returning a value   dating  c:\users\chris\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\dating\dating.c    90  
Warning C4477   'printf' : format string '%s' requires an argument of type 'char *', but variadic argument 1 has type 'int' dating  c:\users\chris\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\dating\dating.c    47  
Warning C4477   'printf' : format string '%s' requires an argument of type 'char *', but variadic argument 2 has type 'int' dating  c:\users\chris\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\dating\dating.c    47  
Warning C4477   'printf' : format string '%s' requires an argument of type 'char *', but variadic argument 3 has type 'int' dating  c:\users\chris\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\dating\dating.c    47  
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _WinMain@16 referenced in function "int __cdecl invoke_main(void)" (?invoke_main@@YAHXZ) dating  c:\Users\Chris\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\dating\MSVCRTD.lib(exe_winmain.obj)    1   
Error   LNK1120 1 unresolved externals  dating  c:\users\chris\documents\visual 

studio 2015\Projects\dating\Debug\dating.exe    1
```

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


//Declares function
void getInput(char *userInput1, char *userInput2, char *userInput3);
//Declares variables.



int main(void) {
    char userInput[100];
    printf("Enter a date in this format : MM/DD/YY:");
    //Captures users input
    scanf("%s", &userInput);
    //Divides the 3 dates entered into 3 variables.
    char *userInput1 = strtok(userInput, "/");
    char *userInput2 = strtok(NULL, "/");
    //Used X to capture the last end of integers entered.
    char *userInput3 = strtok(NULL, "X");
    //Called function.
    getInput(*userInput1, *userInput2, *userInput3);

    system("pause");
    return 0;

}

void getInput(char *userInput1, char *userInput2, char *userInput3)
{
    // If user inputs a valid date this will run.
    if (0 > *userInput1<12, 0>*userInput2<31, 0>*userInput3 < 99) {
        // If user month input is this...
        switch (*userInput1) {

            //if User month input is 02 this will run
        case 02:

            //If user year is a leap year this will run
            if (*userInput3 % 4 == 0) {
                //If user day is inbetween 0-29 it will say the date is valid.
                if (0 > *userInput2 > 29) {
                    printf("You entered a valid date, %s/%s/%s", *userInput1, *userInput2, *userInput3);
                }

                // If the day of the February isn't 0-29 it will print it is invalid.
                else
                    printf("Invalid date.");
            }

        case 04:
            //Their are only 30 days in April, if user Inputs 31 it is invalid.
            if (*userInput2 == 31) {
                printf("Invalid date.");
            }
            //Every other date should be valid because the main if else statement filters it all out.
            else {
                ("You entered a valid date, %s/%s/%s", *userInput1, *userInput2, *userInput3);
            }

        case 06:
            if (*userInput2 == 31) {
                printf("Invalid date.");
            }
            //Every other date should be valid because the main if else statement filters it all out.
            else {
                ("You entered a valid date, %s/%s/%s", *userInput1, *userInput2, *userInput3);
            }

        case 11:
            if (*userInput2 == 31) {
                printf("Invalid date.");
            }

            //Every other date should be valid because the main if else statement filters it all out.
            else {
                ("You entered a valid date, %s/%s/%s", *userInput1, *userInput2, *userInput3);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    //If the user enters a date that isn't valid , Invalid date prints.
    else {
        printf("Invalid date.");
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Microsoft just tries to impose its versions of the standard functions. You can use those. Just turn off those warnings. Read there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30570382/is-strtok-safe-to-use/30570501#30570501

Comment: You are not getting compiler errors for `strtok` and others, you are getting warnings. MSVC has its own ideas how you should be doing it, with Windows non-standard functions, some of which are no "safer" then those they want to replace.

Comment: In MSVC if you place `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` *before* the library header files `#include <...>` it will suppress those warnings. Then the more important warnings such as your use of `print` with `%s` format will still need attention.

Comment: The only thing I can see wrong with your use of `strtok`is you do not check its return value to be `NULL` but syntactically it looks OK. Never rely on input to be what you expect.

Comment: The condition `if (0 > *userInput1<12, 0>*userInput2<31, 0>*userInput3 < 99)` does not do what you think it does.  It always evaluates to true, regardless of the values pointed at by any of the three pointers — make sure you understand why!  You need to write out each term as `(0 > *userinput1 && *userinput1 < 12)`, for example, and you need to combine the three terms with `&&` not the comma operator which evaluates but throws away its left-hand operand and returns the result of evaluating its right-hand operand.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, Oh okay I understand that. I was having trouble determining if I should use , or && . Thanks.

Comment: When you're thinking of whether or not to use the comma operator, the answer 99% of the time is "No".

Comment: Also, please note that there was a major crisis in the late 90s called the Y2K bug (I'm not sure if you were paying attention to such issues back then, but I suspect not), which arose because people didn't properly handle the fact that 2000 is a leap year, even though neither 1900 nor 2100 is.  The rule is 'a leap year is divisible by 400, or a leap year is divisible by 4 and not divisible by 100'.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, How would I go about fixing the Warning C4477 error?

Comment: In the line `printf("You entered a valid date, %s/%s/%s", *userInput1, *userInput2, *userInput3);` the three values passed are the first characters of the strings, not the pointer to the first character.  Remove the `*` — three times.  Note that you don't get a warning from April, June or November because you forgot to include the function name `printf` before the parentheses.  You don't get a warning from September because you haven't remembered "30 days hath September, April, June and November" (or "30 days hath November, April, June and September" — both rhyme).

Comment: Of course, the 30-day cases should all be in one block of code.  Remember that `02`, `04` and `06` are octal numbers; `09` is not a valid octal number.  Best to write `2`, `6`, `9`, `11` as in `case 4: case 6: case 9: case 11:` (spread over 4 lines for preference, but that's not an option in a comment).

Answer (score 0):

You pass characters instead of pointers to `getinput()`:

```
getInput(*userInput1, *userInput2, *userInput3);
```

Try this instead:

```
getInput(userInput1, userInput2, userInput3);
```

The warning you get from the compiler regarding `scanf()` are indications of potential problems:

- `scanf` is unsafe: indeed you do not limit the number of characters to store into the `userInput` array, and you should not pass the address of the array, but the address of its first entry, and you should check the return value:

  ```
  if (scanf("%99s", userInput) != 1) {
      /* handle input failure */
  }
  ```
- `strtok` is unsafe to use in nested contexts. You do not do this in the above code, but it is difficult for the compiler to verify and it would be safer to use `strtok_s` or `strtok_r` instead.

You have further problems in function `getInput()`:

- You should check if any of the arguments are `NULL`.
- `if (0 > *userInput1<12, 0>*userInput2<31, 0>*userInput3 < 99) {` is a valid C expression, but not what you intend to test.  Write this instead:

  ```
  if (*userInput1 > 0 && *userInput1 < 12
  &&  *userInput2 > 0 && *userInput2 < 31
  &&  *userInput3 > 0 && *userInput3 < 99) {
      ...
  }
  ```

  But note however that you are testing characters, not the decimal value encoded into these characters.  You should first convert these strings into numbers with `atoi()` or `strtol()`, or use a different `scanf()` conversion.
- Note that leap years are not strictly multiples of `4`, you might need to use the Gregorian rule if you want to handle years outside the `1901..2099` range. I assume `YY` implies `20YY`, but this would be incorrect if you ask for birthdays.
- You missed that September also has 30 days.

Here is a corrected and simplified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int check_date(int month, int day, int year);

int main(void) {
    char userInput[100];
    int day, month, year;

    printf("Enter a date in this format : MM/DD/YY:");
    //Captures users input
    if (scanf("%d/%d/%d", &month, &day, &year) == 3) {
        check_date(day, month, year);
    } else {
        printf("incorrect input\n");
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;

}

int check_date(int month, int day, int year) {
    int valid = 1;
    // If user inputs a valid date this will run.
    if (month <= 0 || month > 12 || day <= 0 || day > 31 || year < 0 || year > 99) {
        valid = 0;
    } else {
        switch (month) {
            //if User month input is 02 this will run
          case 02:
            //If user year is a leap year this will run
            if (year % 4 == 0) {
                if (day > 29)
                    valid = 0;
            } else {
                if (day <= 28)
                    valid = 0;
            }
            break;
          case 4:
          case 6:
          case 9:
          case 11:
            if (month > 30)
                valid = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (valid) {
        printf("You entered a valid date, %d/%d/%d\n", month, day, year);
        return 1;
    } else {
        printf("Invalid date\n");
        return 0;
    }
}
```